# graphics hardware acceleration 16.04 radeon

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, radeon

I upgraded my Acer Aspire E 15 to Ubuntu 16.04. Now videos are running very slowly if at all.

The laptop contains `AMD Radeon R7` and the radeon driver is used.

But if I run `vdpauinfo` the following is shown:

```
display: :0   screen: 0
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error creating VDPAU device: 1
```

I have no nvidia components installed!

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you need to execute:

```
export VDPAU_DRIVER=radeonsi
export LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=radeonsi
```

so that the right driver is selected (maybe radeon instead of radeonsi).